# How to use epoll and make the handler functions non-blocking?

Tags: c, epoll

I know little about `epoll`, after checking some documents then think it runs like this:

```
while(true){
    epoll_wait(some_sock_fds);
    foreach(usable_fds){
        handler(one_fd);  <----- this function must be non-blocking ?
    }
}
```

In the `handler` function there should be something about network read/write or file operations, I think it should be non-blocking, yes?

How can I write the `handler` function so that it does not block the main loop?

Comment: It can be blocking, epoll waits and gives you only those fds, that would not block, so the handler is guaranteed not to block.

Comment: @RomanHocke in `foreach` loop, handle the first `fd` may cost 5s, the second `fd` should wait 5s, yes?

Comment: "handle the first fd may cost 5s" The data for the first fd is ready, it is guaranteed by epoll, there will be no wait.

Comment: You can spawn a thread in the `handler` and let the new thread do the things you want to do. So it won't block your main loop.  However, you may want to do some synchronization if any of the data is shared.

Comment: @n.m. yes, this fd is ready, but in `handler`, there are db connections or something others will cost time.

Comment: @SSC if use new threads, maybe the epoll model is not necessary. Maybe the problem is adding all `blocking events` into the `epoll_wait` ? I can't confirm this.

Comment: "there are db connections" they have nothing to do with `one_fd`. You don't need non-blocking read on `one_fd`. You do ONE regular read on `one_fd` and return to the epoll loop. If you have other fds you want to operate on, such as database connections and whatnot, don't do non-blocking anything on them, push them to the epoll too and add handlers for them. That's what epoll is all about.

Comment: @n.m.  I can't understand this, for example here I want to make a http server, first make an epoll loop to accept connections, when accept connection`one_fd` then `handler` called, in `handler`, db connections would be made. question is: db connections (or queries) are blocking IO normally, so `handler` is blocked, and of course the `epoll_wait` does not have chance to be called before `handler` returned. so the http server can't handle the next connection? Maybe I'm asking a stupid question, thanks for your patients. :D

Comment: A db connection is made on a socket. You add that socket to the epoll. Everything you neet to wait on is added to epoll. Then you make ONE IO operation on a socket epoll says is ready, and return to epoll. See? No difference between http sockets, database sockets, or ant other sockets. All go to epoll. No IO is done other than on a socket returned from epoll.

Comment: @n.m. Yes!Yes! Thanks you very much! I get it! so things left are all programming skills. I need to make an `event center` like loop to handle all events, and call handlers registered to any `fd` on ready. Maybe this is right ?

Comment: Yes this is exactly right.

Answer (score 0):

The io thread should focus on the network tasks. If the socket is blocked, you should handle every socket in a separate thread. One thread per socket.